# combine three tables with keyword with in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to join three tables. Here is the DB model in server:

```
lecturers
    id - integer (PK)
    ......

examination
    id - integer (PK)
   .....

exam_supervision
    lecturer_id - integer (FK)
    exam_id- integer (FK)
```

Model relation as I implemented in laravel.

```

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Examsupervision extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'exam_supervision';

    protected $fillable = ['lecturer_id', 'exam_id'];
}


<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Examination extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'examination';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'module_id', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'duration', 'type', 'code', 'status'];




}

<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lecturers extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'lecturers';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'address', 'phone'];





}
```

```

lecturers, examinations and exam_supervision which is M:M. What I want is find all the examinations of a lecturer.

My code

```
 public function lecturerViewExaminations($id)
  {


what code to get all exam for a lecturer..say ID 129


  }
```

Returning me empty set. WHat am I doing wrong? It is easy in SQL syntax but in laravel I am finding it very confusing

Comment: Share model relation ?

Comment: Done..Please see edit

Comment: You haven't created any relation

Comment: Good, now create in the model Examsupervision 2 new relations

Answer (score 2):

What i understand from your question is:

You have one model (Examsupervision) and want the relations examinations and lectures

You can use [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

First create a [model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models). In this case your model name would be something like Examsupervision.
In your model(Examsupervision) you can define your relations. In this case examinations and lextures

Create for every relation a new model. So you will have 3 models (Examsupervision, Examinations, Lectures).

Now in your model Examsupervision create a new relation function.

```
public function lectures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lectures');
}
public function examinations(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Examinations');
}
```

In your database table "lectures" and "examinations" create a new key with the name `examsupervision_id`. This key will be the id of the Examsupervision row.

Now in your code when you want the get all the lectures of a given Examsupervision you can do this.

```
$examsupervision = Examsupervision::find($id); //$id = the Examsupervision you want to retrieve
$lectures = $examsupervision->lectures; //This will return all the lectures connected to examsupervision
```

And for examinations you can do the same with:

```
$examsupervision = Examsupervision::find($id); //$id = the Examsupervision you want to retrieve
$examinations = $examsupervision->examinations;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @webion123 : you haven't followed what Wimbledon says. Create model relations

Comment: @webion123 you dont have any relations created. Create the relations in your Examsupervision  model

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `->get()` after the last where.

```
 $examinations= Examsupervision::with('lecturers', 'examinations')->where('lecturer_id', 'id')->where('exam_id', 'id')->get();
```

Comment: still empty [] set

Comment: Does the column `lecturer_id` exist on `lecturers` and `exam_id` on `examinations` or are they in `Examsupervision`. If they are not in `Examsupervision` then take a look at `Constraining Eager Loads` on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Please share the `Examsupervision` model

Answer (score 0):

`Model::with()` is for relation, Use just `->get()`

```
$examinations=Examsupervision::with('lecturers', 'examinations')->get();
```

You already have relation for `lecturers` and `examinations`.

If not worked, share Model `Examsupervision`

Comment: @webion123 :  Share your model if any relation ?